# C++ read "enter" in command line

Tags: c++, shell, command

I have a very simple question.

I have a project like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string file_name;
    cin >> file_name;
    ifstream file(file_name);
    if(file.good()){
        cout << "File can be loaded";
    }
    else{
        cout << "Default file will be loaded";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the command line, if I just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on my keyboard, I want to read nothing in `file_name` and then it will load a default file automatically. The current situation is it will wait until I type in something.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the "default file"?

Comment: `cin>> file_name;` you probably want to use std::getline() to allow for a user typing a file name  / path with spaces.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks. It got fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator>>` discards leading whitespace first (unless the `skipws` flag is disabled on the stream), and then reads until whitespace is encountered. <kbd>Enter</kbd> generates a `'\n'` character, which `operator>>` treated as whitepace.

For what you want to do, use `std::getline()` instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string file_name;
    getline(cin, file_name);
    if (file_name.empty()) {
        file_name = "default name here";
        cout << "Default file will be loaded" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << file_name << " will be loaded" << endl;
    }

    ifstream file(file_name);
    if(file.is_open()){
        cout << "File is opened" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "File is not opened" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```